# However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, system.reactive

This is the first time I use mockito with kotlin mvp Rx
And, I got an error "wanted but not invoked - However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock"

Here my presenter class

```
class MatchPresenter(private val matchContract: MatchContract,private val apiService: MatchService,private val appSchedulerProvider: AppSchedulerProvider) {

fun getLastMatch() {
            apiService
            .getLastMatches()
            .subscribeOn(appSchedulerProvider.newThread())
            .observeOn(appSchedulerProvider.ui())
            .subscribe(
                    { matchList ->
                        matchContract.onSuccess(matchList)
                    },
                    { error ->
                        matchContract.onFailed(error.message)
                    }
            )
}

fun getNextMatch() {
            apiService
            .getNextMatches()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    { matchList ->
                        matchContract.onSuccess(matchList)
                    },
                    { error ->
                        matchContract.onFailed(error.message)
                    }
            )
}
```

Here my presenter view

```
interface MatchContract {
fun onFailed(message: String?)
fun onSuccess(matchModel: MatchModel)
```

}
Here my AppSchedulerProvider
class AppSchedulerProvider : SchedulerProvider {
    override fun trampoline(): Scheduler {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

```
override fun newThread(): Scheduler {
    return Schedulers.newThread()
}

override fun ui(): Scheduler {
    return AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
}

override fun computation(): Scheduler {
    return Schedulers.computation()
}

override fun io(): Scheduler {
    return Schedulers.io()
}
```

}

and here my presenterTest

```
class MatchPresenterTest {
@Mock
private lateinit var view:MatchContract




@Mock
private lateinit var apiService: MatchService

@Mock
private lateinit var appSchedulerProvider: AppSchedulerProvider

private lateinit var presenter : MatchPresenter

@Before
fun setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(object : RxAndroidSchedulersHook() {
        override fun getMainThreadScheduler(): Scheduler {
            return Schedulers.immediate() // or .test()
        }
    })
    presenter = MatchPresenter(view,apiService,appSchedulerProvider)
}


@Test
fun getLastMatch_shoul_callSucces(){
    val event: MutableList<EventModel> = mutableListOf()
    val response = MatchModel(event)
    RxJavaHooks.setOnIOScheduler { scheduler1 -> Schedulers.immediate() }

    Mockito.`when`(apiService.getLastMatches()
    ).thenReturn(Observable.just(response))


    presenter.getLastMatch()

    verify(view).onSuccess(response)
    verify(view).onFailed("failed")

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the verification for view.onFailed in the last line of your test. Other than that, you did everything right.